# Verify signature using elliptic curve cryptography

Tags: java, security, digital-signature, jce, elliptic-curve

I need to verify a signature of a message which contains several values. The only parameters I have are the signature, the public key and the values itself. The algorithm used for creating the signature is eliptic curve cryptography with 192 bit. I allready tried to find code examples on the net but I didn't find anything for this case.

Has anybody experiences with this algorithm using java for verification? Could you please provide code or a link to an example?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably use [Bouncy Castle](http://bouncycastle.org/index.html) library.

See http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Using+Elliptic+Curve

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately the link to bouncycastle wiki does not work, I always get a server error.

Comment: @Skiontke yeah it's not working for me at the moment either, that's why I couldn't send you a more elaborated reply. It might be down temporarily...

Comment: @SKiontke javadocs here: http://bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.6/index.html check classes starting with EC...

Answer (score 5):

You are a bit short on information there...

There are several signature schemes which use elliptic curves, but the most widespread (by far) is [ECDSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_DSA). You must then worry about the following points:

- Signature operates on a sequence of bits. Every single data bit must be correct. Here, you have "values" so there must be an encoding of those values into a sequence of bits (or bytes). To verify the signature, you must use the same encoding than the one used to generate the signature.
- ECDSA begins by hashing the input data with a [cryptographic hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function). There again, you must use the same one than what was used for generating the signature. As a wild guess, I would say that the hash function is probably [SHA-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1).
- ECDSA operates in an [elliptic curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve). The curve *size* is not enough to define the curve: there are many 192-bit curves. However, since defining your own curve is hard, most people use one curve among the 15 curves defined in [FIPS 186-3](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips186-3/fips_186-3.pdf). One of those 15 curves has a "192-bit size" (it is called "P-192") so chances are that the signature uses that curve.
- An ECDSA public key is the encoding of a curve point. A curve point is, nominally, a pair of integers *(X, Y)* (these are the "coordinates" of the point). These integers are from the base field in which the curve lives; for the P-192 curve, the coordinates are 192-bit integers. The "normal" encoding for such a public key is then a 49-byte string: the first byte will be 0x02, followed by the big-endian unsigned encoding of *X* (24 bytes), then the unsigned encoding of *Y* (24 bytes). Other encodings are possible.
- An ECDSA signature formally consists in two integer values, usually called *r* and *s* (192-bit integers too). There again, the signature you have is probably a sequence of bytes which is an encoding of the two integers. There are two common encodings, one being a raw big-endian unsigned encoding of both value (hence a 48-byte signature), the other using ASN.1 (for a signature of length 53 or 54  bytes, or so).

Using [Bouncy Castle](http://bouncycastle.org/index.html), as @Ashkan suggests, is a good idea. But, as you see, there are quite a lot of assumptions to do about your situation. If you want to gain a thorough understanding of what is going on, buy a copy of [ANSI X9.62:2005](http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=ANSI%20X9.62:2005) (the ECDSA standard). Be warned that the mathematical contents are quite heavy.